# Realm.js Queries on list of strings property

Tags: javascript, realm

### Goals

filtered list of strings property

### Code Sample

```
const BookrackSchema = {
    name: 'Bookrack',
    properties: {
        book_names:'string[]',
    }
};

Bookrack1.book_names=['A','B','C'];
Bookrack2.book_names=['B','C','D'];
Bookrack3.book_names=['C','D','E'];

a:realm.objects('Bookrack').filtered(`ANY book_names = $0 `,'B');
b:realm.objects('Bookrack').filtered(`book_names CONTAINS  $0 `,'B');
```

### Expected Results

get Bookrack1 And Bookrack2

### Actual Results

```
aResult:The keypath following 'ANY' or 'SOME' must contain a list

bResult:Object type 'Table' not supported
```

Comment: It's not supported in any bindings at this time. If it bothers you, raise hell here: https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/issues/513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Realm JS only support querying list of objects but we plan to add support for querying list of primitive types. Until then, you could use something like:

```
const Realm = require('realm');

const BookrackSchema = {
    name: 'Bookrack',
    properties: {
        book_names:'string[]',
    }
};

let realm = new Realm({schema: [BookrackSchema]});

realm.write(() => {
    realm.create('Bookrack', { book_names: ['A','B','C']});
    realm.create('Bookrack', { book_names: ['B','C','D']});
    realm.create('Bookrack', { book_names: ['C','D','E']});
});

let objs = realm.objects('Bookrack');
let Bs = objs.filter(obj => { return obj.book_names.reduce((acc, cur)  => { return acc || cur === 'B' }, false)});
```